# Swift 4 JSON Parsing Int - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: json, swift4, codable

Swift 4 JSON Parsing Int issue.   All the examples I've seen Int is encoded / decoded out of the box.  Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

JSON

```
let patientBundleEntry = """
{
"resourceType": "Bundle",
"id": "patientListBundle",
"type": "SearchSet",
"total": 123
}
"""
```

Classes

```
class BundleFHIR: Resource {
var entry:[BundleEntry]?
var total:Int?   // this is printing -> Optional(105553116787496) instead of 123
}


class Resource:Codable {

var resourceType:ResourceType?  // this is printing fine
}
```

Test - my assert for total being 123 fails and the optional is a long number.  Any ideas why?  Is my encoding wrong using .utf8??

```
func testModelBundle(){

    let jsonDataEncoded:Data? = patientBundleEntry.data(using: .utf8)!

    guard let responseData = jsonDataEncoded else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")

    }


    do {
        let bundleDecoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(BundleFHIR.self, from: responseData)

        print("bundleDecoded.resourceType resource type \(bundleDecoded.resourceType )")  //THIS is right
        print("bundleDecoded.resourceType total \(bundleDecoded.total )")  THIS is wrong 

        assert(bundleDecoded.total == 123, "something is wrong")  // ***** <- this assert fails and it prints Optional(105553116787496) 


    } catch {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")

    }
}
```

Comment: This has to do with inheritance.  I will update this with the answer in a few.  But this is very odd.

Answer (score 2):

At first you have to decode and then parse the JSON data.

**Follow the below code :**

```
struct Patient: Codable {
        var resourceType: String
        var id: String
        var type: String
        var total: Int
    }

let json = patientBundleEntry.data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let patient = try! decoder.decode(Patient.self, from: json)

print(patient.total) // Prints - 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok there were a lot of issues with my code.  Mainly that I didn't have codingKeys as private and therefore tried to rename it because the inheritance tree could not discern between the two.  This caused me to not be implementing the true protocol.  Not sure why it was half working... but here is my final code and it works great!

```
class BundleFHIR: Resource {
var entry:[BundleEntry]?
var total:Int?


override init() {
    super.init()
}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {


    try super.init(from: decoder)

    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    total = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .total)
    entry = try values.decodeIfPresent([BundleEntry].self, forKey: .entry)
}

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
{
    case total
    case entry
}
```

}

```
 class Resource:Codable {

var resourceType:ResourceType?
var id:String?

init(){

}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)


    resourceType = try values.decode(ResourceType.self, forKey: .resourceType)
    id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
}

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
{
    case resourceType
    case id
}
}
```